# Incrementing a volatile variable in C

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, volatile

Consider the following three expressions:

```
++x;
x += 1;
x = x + 1;
```

As far as I'm aware, they are identical in semantics, ignoring operator overloading in C++.  However, today I read an assertion that they are different, specifically when `x` is declared `volatile`.

To test this assertion, I wrote the following and compiled it for PowerPC, AMD64, ARMv6 and 68k:

```
#include <stdint.h>

static volatile uint64_t x = 0;

void a(void)
{
    ++x;
}

void b(void)
{
    x += 1;
}

void c(void)
{
    x = x + 1;
}
```

On all four of these platforms, the three functions produced identical assembler output, whether at -O1 or -O3.  On AMD64, that was just two instructions:

```
incq    _x(%rip)
retq
```

Therefore, *is* there any truth behind that assertion?  If so, what is the difference, and how can I expose it?

NB: I'm perfectly aware that `volatile` doesn't guarantee atomicity.  That's not what I'm asking about here - unless the atomicity itself is what is different between the three.

Comment: C11 draft standard, `6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators Section 2 [...]The expression ++E is equivalent to (E+=1).[...]`. `6.5.16.2 Compound assignment, Section 3 [...]A compound assignment of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent to the simple assignment
expression E1 = E1 op (E2), except that the lvalue E1 is evaluated only once[...]`

Comment: @EOF OP might be more interested in the third case as there seems to be a read and a write access in the expression, which should be reflected in machine code ... about to check this

Comment: Footnote at C11§6.5.16/3: `111) The implementation is permitted to read the object to determine the value but is not required to, even when the object has volatile-qualified type.`

Comment: Ok, only this footnote clarifies this is not a compiler bug ;) (and there were many around `volatile`). Yet another implementation-defined situation I wasn't aware of ...

Comment: @Kninnug: Interesting. But the way I read this, that is about an expression like `b = a = whatever`, where the value of the right assignment is used further.

Comment: @Kninnug footnotes are not normative and the draft C++ standard does not seem to have a similar note.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, wait ... one step back: `x = x + 1;` clearly contains a read and a write. What about `++x`? On the assembly level, `inc` fetches and stores, so it's both...

Comment: @FelixPalmen: More importantly, the volatile read and the volatile store are not reordered with each other in the `incq`. Obviously, since they are dependent.

Comment: @EOF That's one assertion, the other one is that every fetch and store actually happens *exactly once*. So if on the C level, `++x` is considered doing both, everything is fine I guess.

Comment: Well, semantically those forms are different. The first one is increment, while the second is simply a shorthand for the third one, which is NOT increment, but rather three operations - read, addition, and assignment. I believe, compilers replacing 3 operations with single increment for volatile is not neccessarily correct.

Comment: @SergeyA: Did you read my first comment? If so, why do you claim "[...]the second is simply a shorthand for the third one[...]" when the standard clearly contradicts this?

Comment: @SergeyA - How can you increment a value if you don't read it to know what it is?  What is "increment" other than "read, addtion, and assignment"?

Comment: Someone should condense this to a good answer. Is it stated by the standard that e.g. `++x` means a read and a write? Or is it just "common sense"?

Comment: @EOF's quote from the standard matches my previous understanding of the relationship between the three expressions.  I note also: `5.1.2.3 Program Execution [...] Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment. Evaluation of an expression in general includes both value
computations and initiation of side effects.`

Comment: @SergeyA An AMD64 CPU internally converts `inc` into distinct read, modify and write operations.  To make it an atomic, indivisible operation (as seen by other CPUs) it would need to be `lock inc`.

Comment: @JSF It does - that's the context of footnote 111 as per Kninnug's comment (ie. it punts on the issue).

Comment: @Chromatix whether it's atomic shouldn't matter. I think what SergeyA missed here is just the fact that `inc` *will* fetch and store the value, at least on any architecture I know...

Comment: @FelixPalmen That's what I was trying to convey.  :)

Comment: Clearly this has no impact on any portable behavior of `volatile`. So any differences would be platform specific.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the draft C++ standard section `5.3.2` *[expr.pre.incr]* says:

> If x is not of type bool, the expression ++x is equivalent to x+=1

and `5.17` *[expr.ass]* says:

> The behavior of an expression of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent to
>   E1 = E1 op E2 except that E1 is evaluated only once.

So `++x` and `x += 1` are equivalent.

Now the one case where `x += 1` differs from `x = x + 1` is that `E1` is only evaluated once. In this particular case it does not matter but we can come up with a case where it does:

```
#include <stdint.h>

volatile uint64_t x = 0;
volatile uint64_t y[2] = {0} ;

void c(void)
{
   y[x] = y[x] + 1;
}
```

in this case the `x` will be evaluated twice as opposed to this case:

```
void b(void)
{
   y[x] += 1;
}
```

and a [godbolt session shows](http://goo.gl/Z2L6Qw) for `b()`:

```
b():                                  # @b()
movq    x(%rip), %rax
incq    y(,%rax,8)
retq
```

and for `c()`:

```
c():                                  # @c()
movq    x(%rip), %rax
movq    y(,%rax,8), %rax
incq    %rax
movq    x(%rip), %rcx
movq    %rax, y(,%rcx,8)
retq
```

As far as I can tell this applies to C11 as well. From C11 section `6.5.3.1` Prefix increment and decrement operators:

> The expression ++E is equivalent to (E+=1).

and from section `6.5.16.2` Compound assignment:

> Acompound assignment of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to the simple
>   assignment expression E1 = E1 op (E2), except that the lvalue E1 is
>   evaluated only once

Comment: Interesting that it says "if not of type bool".  What about types with operator overloading defined?  (Yes, I'm being pedantic.)

Comment: @Chromatix overloaded operators will translate into a function call and will depend on the implementation so the standard can not provide a guarantee for those cases.

Comment: @Chromatix with respect to the bool case the standard says `The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1, or set to true if it is bool (this use is deprecated).` so it is strictly not equivalent and it is a depreciated usage.

Comment: I've added the array-access test cases to my program, and they also produce different code from each other on other architectures.  Interestingly, the address computations for `y[x] = y[x] + 1` are pipelined on RISC platforms, so that the fetches of `x` for both occur *before* the fetch of `y[x]`.

Comment: @Chromatix I noticed gcc does the same thing but clang does not, I am not sure what to think about that.

Comment: AFAIK, the statement doesn't contain any sequence points, so reordering the accesses is allowed even though it involves volatile objects.  That's one of the reasons why volatile isn't atomic.

Comment: @Chromatix duh, that is correct, not sure what I was thinking. In C11/C++11 speak the order of evaluation is unspecified.

Comment: `y[x] = y[x] + 1` has nothing to do with `x = x + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

In the abstract semantics, all three of these expressions do exactly the same thing. They *access* `x` to retrieve its value, calculate the new value, then store the updated value back in `x`. There is an access and a store.  (The expressions also yield a value, which is being discarded).

Although `x = x + 1` mentions `x` twice, the left side `x` isn't evaluated. That is to say, not completely: its *value* is not computed. It is evaluated only to the extent of determining the location where the assigned value will go.

So there is possibly a double evaluation of location here: the left side determines the location of `x` and so does the right side. But determining location doesn't involve accessing the location itself.

For some kinds of expressions, determining the location does involve accessing values. For example:

```
a[i] = a[i] + 1;
```

This is quite different from

```
i = i + 1
```

because `i` is only a secondary variable here whose value must be known in order to determine the storage location of `a[i]` (and `i` isn't itself even being incremented). If `i` is `volatile`, then the two abstract accesses to it in `a[i] = a[i] + 1` must correspond to two actual accesses.